# What is the impact of spinlock between two threads on uniprocessor system

Tags: linux-kernel

1. 

### List item

What happens when we use spinlock on uniprocessor system with two threads running.

Comment: Nothing, there is no locking. I.o.w. locking is no-op on UP systems. UP may not have more than **one** thread _running_ by definition.

Answer (score 0):

The thread in a spinlock would wait spinning until its execution is interrupted by a timer interrupt. As the kernel handles the interrupt, it calls the scheduler, which might decide the timeslice of the thread has expired and schedule the second thread.

Comment: Not explicitly *timer*, any interrupt is considered. More interesting case is `spin_lock_irqsave()`. What about it?